$\max |\sum_i s_i(a_i+b_i)|+|\sum_i s_i(a_i-b_i)|$ such that $s_i\in\{\pm1\}$
Given $n>0$ and two number arrays $\{a_i:1\leq i\leq n\},\{b_i:1\leq i\leq n\}$ and $\forall i, a_i\geq0,b_i\geq 0$, what is the value of this:
\begin{align*}
    &\max |\sum_i s_i(a_i+b_i)|+|\sum_i s_i(a_i-b_i)|\\
    \text{s.t }& \forall i,~ s_i\in\{\pm1\}
\end{align*}
Can this value be expressed in terms of $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$? One trivial upper bound is $\sum_i(a_i+b_i)+\sum_i|a_i-b_i|$ but the equality does not always hold.

By flipping all the $s_i$, we can assume that the first sum is non-negative, so we can drop the first absolute value.
Then there are two cases, depending on whether the second sum is non-negative.
If the second sum is non-negative, you are maximizing: $$\displaystyle \sum_i s_i(a_i+b_i)+\sum_i s_i(a_i-b_i) = 2\sum_i s_i\,a_i$$
Otherwise, you are maximizing:
$$\displaystyle
    \sum_i s_i(a_i+b_i)-\sum_i s_i(a_i-b_i) = 2\sum_i s_i\,b_i
$$
So the optimal value is $2\max(\sum_i a_i, \sum_i b_i)$
